# Active Record association in rails for a Secret Santa type buyer/receiver relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Trying to get my head around the correct tables and associations for a user model to be related in such a way that a user can be both the buyer and receiver of gifts to/from other users. Each user should only be a buyer for one other user and only be a receiver from one other user.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need a simple migration with a couple of validation.

```
rails generate migration AddSantaRefToUsers
```

Edit migration to be:

```
class AddSantaRefToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :santa_id, :integer
    add_index :users, :santa_id
  end
end
```

Run migration `rake db:migrate` then update your User model.

```
class User
  has_one :santa, foreign_key: 'santa_id'
  belongs_to :santa, class_name: 'User'

  validate :can_be_santa
  validates :santa_id, uniqueness: true # this means no duplicate Santas

  private
  def can_be_santa
    if self.santa == self
      self.errors.add(user_id:, "You can't be your own Santa!")
    end
  end
end
```

Then making someone another user's Santa should be as easy as:

```
user1.santa = user2
```